# InkWell Issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter

The idea was to blur the background and its components as soon as the FabCircularMenu(except for this) is clicked. The little slot machine-like icon hanging at the top right corner of the screen has an InkWell wrapped around it to take me to another page. Although the Inkwell works just fine, it seems to be all over the place as clicking anywhere else on the screen tends to navigate to the next page. Here's the code and the screenshot:

[image]

The blue arrow points at the FabCircularMenu button while the red shows the slot machine thing.

```
class _StoryScreenState extends State<StoryScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<FabCircularMenuState> fabKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey<FabCircularMenuState> fabKeyOne = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Story story = widget.stories![_currentIndex];
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    //Bottom Circular Menu
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (details) => _onTapDown(details, story),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Blur(
                  blur: blurValue,
                  colorOpacity: 0.01,
                  child: PageView.builder(
                    controller: _pageController,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: widget.stories!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      final Story story = widget.stories![i];

                      return HomeTabView(
                        backgroundImagePath: story.url!,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Blur(
                  blur: blurValue,
                  colorOpacity: 0.01,
                  child: Positioned(
                    top: 20.0,
                    left: 10.0,
                    right: 10.0,
                    child: Container(
                      height: height * 0.3,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      // color: Colors.red,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: widget.stories!
                                .asMap()
                                .map((i, e) {
                                  return MapEntry(
                                    i,
                                    AnimatedBar(
                                      animController: _animController!,
                                      position: i,
                                      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
                                    ),
                                  );
                                })
                                .values
                                .toList(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          //Slot Icon
          InkWell(
            onTap: () => Get.toNamed("/slot-machine"),
            child: Blur(
              colorOpacity: 0.01,
              blur: blurValue,
              child: Positioned(
                right: width * 0.02,
                bottom: height * 0.84,
                child: Container(
                  height: height * 0.2,
                  width: width * 0.3,
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/slot-icon.svg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FabCircularMenu(
            key: fabKeyOne,
            onDisplayChange: (isOpen) {
              // isPressed ? _pressed = true : _pressed = false;
              isOpen
                  ? setState(() {
                      blurValue = 8;
                    })
                  : setState(() {
                      blurValue = 0;
                    });
              print('Post Click ${blurValue}');
            },
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            ringColor: Colors.transparent,
            ringDiameter: 300.0,
            ringWidth: 100.0,
            fabSize: 50.0,
            fabElevation: 8.0,
            fabColor: Colors.transparent,
            fabOpenIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            fabCloseIcon: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            fabMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
            animationCurve: Curves.bounceIn,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(right: width * 0.03, bottom: height * 0.08),
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/profile-page'),
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/user.svg'),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: width * 0.07, bottom: height * 0.065),
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () => Get.toNamed("/notify"),
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/notification.svg'),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(right: width * 0.1, bottom: height * 0.03),
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/search.svg'),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(right: width * 0.1, bottom: height * 0.001),
                child: RawMaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/home'),
                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/home.svg',
                      color: Colors.blue),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have used the blur package to implement this. Alternatively, I tried wrapping only the container instead of Wrapping the entire Blur widget but this doesn't do anything. Any suggestions would be welcome

```
Blur(
      colorOpacity: 0.01,
      blur: blurValue,
      child: Positioned(
        right: width * 0.02,
        bottom: height * 0.84,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => Get.toNamed("/slot-machine"),
          child: Container(
            height: height * 0.2,
            width: width * 0.3,
            // color: Colors.red,
            child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svgs/slot-icon.svg'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Opacity](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) to fix this problem.

Comment: I don't see how opacity can solve this when I really need the background to have a blurred out effect. Moreover, assuming I go with Opacity,  would that make the Inkwell work?